# Mac - How to programmatically hide NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory or LSUIElement application?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a small Swift-based Cocoa app that I'm writing. It's a single window app, something like Spotlight/QuickSilver/Alfred. It's set as `NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSApplicationActivationOptions)) (though I've tried the same thing using `LSUIElement`, which is equivalent). It's activated via a global hot key.

Everything works well, except that when it's active I can't hide the application using `NSRunningApplication.currentApplication().hide()`.

[The docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRunningApplication/hide) for the hide method say "The property of this value will be `NO` if the application has already quit, or **if of a type that is unable to be hidden**." (emphasis mine), and I'm getting a `NO` back (though I'm actually using Swift, so I'm getting `false`).

I can understand why a `NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited` app wouldn't be able to be hidden, since it's never active, but it's confusing to me that this would be the case with `NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory` too.

I tried `myWindow.orderOut(self);`, but that just hides the window without hiding my application and returning focus to the previous app.

I do store a reference to the previously active application, so if need be I can manually activate that app again, but I'm hoping there is a cleaner method of doing this.

Comment: Have you tried `NSApplication.sharedApplication().hide(nil)`? One would normally address the application object (instance of `NSApplication`) rather than an instance of `NSRunningApplication` to operate on the current app.

Comment: @KenThomases That did it! Thanks! Can you write this as an answer so I can mark it as the right one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `NSApplication.sharedApplication().hide(nil)`. One would normally address the application object (instance of `NSApplication`) rather than an instance of `NSRunningApplication` to operate on the current app.

Comment: Swift 4: NSApplication.shared.hide(nil)

Answer (score 0):

The manual solution is to store a reference to the previously active  `NSRunningApplication` instance (called `previouslyActiveApplication` below), and then activate it when you want to deactivate your `NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory` application, like so:

```
previouslyActiveApplication!.activateWithOptions(NSApplicationActivationOptions.ActivateIgnoringOtherApps);
```